# ¿Siempre debo utilizar un servlet para trabajar con aplicaciones web?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlets

Quiero crear una aplicación web utilizando Java. Tengo algunos conocimientos del lenguaje, y al buscar en tutoriales en línea siempre mencionan la creación de un `servlet`. ¿Es necesario aprender y utilizar servlets para crear este tipo de aplicaciones? ¿Es posible crear una aplicación web en Java donde no tenga que utilizar un servlet en absoluto?

Nota: utilizar un framework como `Spring`, `MVC` o `JSF` también exige el uso de un servlet, aunque yo no tenga que codificar el `servlet` por mi cuenta. Considerar esto al momento de la respuesta.

Comment: no creo que nadie te obligue. tranquilamente puedes crear una aplicación que escuche el puerto 80 y que hable HTTP.

Comment: ¿Alguna razón para los votos en contra?

Comment: Yo pregunto lo mismo.

Comment: Los votos en contra probablemente sean por la misma razón que los votos de cierre: la pregunta se considera demasiado amplia o difusa.

Comment: @Konamiman no veo lo amplio en la pregunta. Es concisa, consta de un SÍ o NO y explicar por qué. Cualquier persona que ha desarrollado aplicaciones web con Java puede responder y entender esta pregunta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No me tienes que convencer a mí, sino a la comunidad, que es la que ha emitido los votos :-) Quizá podrías mejorar la pregunta añadiendo cualquier dato interesante que hayas averiguado investigando sobre el tema preguntando. Yo en este caso voy a mantenerme neutral.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia.

Comment: @Gemasoft puedes explicarme que es lo amplio? En realidad no le veo lo amplio. Sólo se trata de decir si o no y por qué. Y eso explico en mi respuesta (que extrañamente solo recibe votos en contra como si creyesen que la fuese a aceptar para ganar reputación) pero al parecer o no leen o simplemente a nadie le gusta explicar que hay de malo.

Answer (score 4):

Si quieres evitar el uso de Servlets en Java EE, es imposible, algo muy diferente es desarrollar con Servlets, por que aunque (por ejemplo) Spring utilice Servlets internamente tu ya no necesitaras crear servlets.

Junto con las nuevas tecnologias han aparecido diferentes frameworks con un enfoque mas minimalista y menos robusto a lo que da Java EE, en este caso puedo citar Spark Java que es framework sencillo y parecido a lo que esta de moda actualmente para el desarrollo de microservicios para aplicaciones web, no confundir con Apache Spark que esta relacionado con el Big Data.

En teoria Spark Java no necesita un servidor de aplicaciones pues utiliza uno embebido(Jety), algo muy parecido a lo que hace SpringBoot que se apoya en todo Java EE y utiliza un tomcat embebido.

http://sparkjava.com

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: Hace poco me enteré de la existencia de Spark Java y la verdad que es muy útil para hacer aplicaicones mínimas que soporten ciclos request/response HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

La razon por la cual existen los `servlets` en primer lugar es para generarle contenido dinámico al cliente.

En un principio el cliente le hace una petición al `servidor`, pero éste **SÓLO** puede brindar contenido **estático** reduciendo mucho el uso de la web cierto ? De ahí nacen los servlets para ayudar al servidor proveer contenido dinámico.

El servlet es mantenido y vive a petición del `contenedor web` quien se encarga de generar instancias de éstos y de facilitar el uso de `JSP` los cuales son simplemente `servlets` que son creados por el `contenedor web`. entre otras cosas.

En últimas, un `servlet` es un programa hecho en `java` el cual no tiene un método `main` sino que contiene unos métodos que generan `callbacks`, y los servlets se comunican con el servidor gracias al `contenedor web` también conocido como `motor de servlets`.

Answer (score -1):

No forzosamente, aunque tu pregunta es excesivamente amplia, puedes usar otras tecnologías como por ejemplo [Dukescript](https://dukescript.com/), que si bien te manejan Java para el *backend*, en el *frontend* no usan ninguna clase relacionada con la interfaz `Servlet`.

En el caso de `Dukescript`, la arquitectura es en esencia cliente-cliente, y normalmente se hace el *binding* de las variables mediante la API knockout para Java, siendo la implementación del frontend libre para cualquier tecnología y/o framework compatible con `Html5` (incluido `css`).

En el caso de aplicaciones web que usen JEE, para usar `EJB` deberás de tener un servidor con contenedor para beans, aunque puedes usar *template engines* en lugar de los Servelets y derivados por ejemplo [Free Marker](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/), [Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) o [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/translations/user-guide_es.html).

Adjunto además [un ejemplo](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/meaningful_html_java_dukescript_framework) de uso de [dukescript](/questions/tagged/dukescript) con un *EntityManager* para consultar una base de datos, en el que obviamente no se usan servlets.

Comment: Si te refieres al uso de EJB, la creación de web services vía JAX-WS se va a crear un servlet en el aire para soportar las solicitudes hechas a la(s) URL(s).

Comment: Solamente si expones el EJB como webservice, pero en la pregunta no se especifica que se usen servicios web, sino aplicaciones web.

Comment: Bueno, si usas solo EJBs en tu aplicación, no se de que otra manera se pueda utilizar desde la web :o

Comment: Hola @LuiggiMendoza adjunté un pequeño ejemplo, espero sea de tu interés :)

Comment: Interesante ejemplo :) lo revisaré con más detalle. Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar páginas JSP. Las páginas JSP son como Servlets "al reves", es decir, mientras en los servlets casi todo está en Java y cuando quieres general HTML imprimes cadenas con `out.println()`, en JSP casi todo es HTML y cuando quieres lógica Java, lo escribes dentro de etiquetas especiales.

Las páginas JSP son compiladas, convirtiéndose en servlets en tiempo ejecución, pero abstraen al programador de las complicaciones de los servlets.